# git pull could not read from .git/MERGE_MSG (file was never created)

Tags: git, git-pull

Have anyone seen this error before when doing a git pull, and how do you resolve it?

```
F:\git\test-results-db>git pull origin bugfix/duplicate-test-times
From {stash_server_URL}
* branch            bugfix/duplicate-test-times -> FETCH_HEAD
Can't do inplace edit on .git/MERGE_MSG: Permission denied.
fatal: Could not read from '.git/MERGE_MSG': No such file or directory
```

This has happened before for the user in question and the last time we created a new branch as a workaround.

Thanks,

Mikael

Answer (score 2):

From the error message it seems that the user has no permissions on .git/MERGE_MSG.

Try the following:

```
rm -F .git/MERGE_MSG
```

Comment: Tried that, but the .git/MERGE_MSG was never created in the .git directory, and the user has full permissions in that directory.